# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,ConsumerRecords<String,Supplier>> to ConsumerRecords<String,Supplier>

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm getting these errors when I'm trying to run my `SupplierConsumer` class in eclipse. Here is my code:

```
public class SupplierConsumer{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

            String topicName = "SupplierTopic";
            String groupName = "SupplierTopicGroup";

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093");
            props.put("group.id", groupName);
            props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
            props.put("value.deserializer", "SupplierDeserializer");


            KafkaConsumer<String, Supplier> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));

            while (true){
                    ConsumerRecords<String, Supplier> records = consumer.poll(100);
                    for (ConsumerRecord<String, Supplier> record : records){
                            System.out.println("Supplier id= " + String.valueOf(record.value().getID()) + " Supplier  Name = " + record.value().getName() + " Supplier Start Date = " + record.value().getStartDate().toString());
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

1. Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<String>` to `String`,
2. Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Map<String,ConsumerRecords<String,Supplier>>` to `ConsumerRecords<String,Supplier>`

Comment: Where exactly do the errors occur? Mark the line with a comment or add a minimal stacktrace.

Comment: 1 error is coming here consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));

Comment: and 2nd error is at  consumer.poll(100);

Answer (score -1):

I think you've inadvertently included on your classpath some pre-release version of the kafka-clients library. I found the signatures that match your compilation errors in v0.8.2-beta:

http://supergsego.com/apache/kafka/0.8.2-beta/java-doc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

If you make sure you use a release quality version of kafka-clients jar (v0.9 or later), your code should compile.

Comment: The link does not work. Fix or delete.

Comment: This is a post from 6 years ago.